# Not able to iterate arraylist of hashmap with JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, arraylist, jstl

I am unable to print or fetch data from arraylist of hashmap using jstl. I want to display details like bug_id,creation date, summary, whiteboard of each bug present in arraylist in a table. Below are jsp and servlet code. Please suggest fix.

home.jsp:-

```
<form action="IncomingBugs">
<table class="ui single line table">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>Bug Id</th>
  <th>Creation Date</th>
  <th>Summary</th>
  <th>Whiteboard</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <c:forEach var="row" items="${list}"> 
    <tr>
    <td><c:out value="${row.bug_id}"/></td>
    <td><c:out value="${row.creation_ts}"/></td>
    <td><c:out value="${row.short_desc}"/></td>
    <td><c:out value="${row.status_whiteboard}"/></td>
</tr>
 </c:forEach> 
 </tbody>
 </table>
 </form>
```

IncomingBugs.jsp:-

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            OracleConnection oc=new OracleConnection();

    try {
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> bugList=oc.getbugList(null);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> blr=new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
         for (HashMap<String, Object> bugMap : bugList) 
        {
             HashMap<String,String> bl=new HashMap<String, String>();
             String bugzilla_id = bugMap.get("bug_id").toString();
             String creation_ts = bugMap.get("creation_ts").toString();
             String short_desc = bugMap.get("short_desc").toString();
             String status_whiteboard=bugMap.get("status_whiteboard").toString();
             bl.put("bug_id", bugzilla_id);
             bl.put("creation_ts", creation_ts);
             bl.put("short_desc", short_desc);
             bl.put("status_whiteboard", status_whiteboard);
             blr.add(bl);
        }
         request.setAttribute("list",blr);
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/home.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);

    }
```

Below is java sample code of what I want to print in table:-

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> bugList = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>)request.getAttribute("list");
 for (HashMap<String, Object> bugMap : bugList) 
{           
     String bugzilla_id = bugMap.get("bug_id").toString();
     String creation_ts = bugMap.get("creation_ts").toString();
     String summary = bugMap.get("summary").toString();
     String status_whiteboard=bugMap.get("status_whiteboard").toString();
     out.println("<tr>");
     out.println("<td>"+bugzilla_id+"</td>");
     out.println("<td>"+creation_ts+"</td>");
     out.println("<td>"+summary+"</td>");
     out.println("<td>"+status_whiteboard+"</td>");
     out.println("</tr>");
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error message? Or what do you expect and can not get with this code? *suggest fix* is not a question.

Comment: I am not getting any error. I want to print bug_id, creation_ts, summary, status_whiteboard in table. I have tried using java in jsp but still its not working https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46042030/http-status-500-unable-to-fetch-details-from-hashmap-to-jsp

Comment: Doesn't JSP EL check scopes? It's been a long time, but you're setting a request *attribute*.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<td><c:out value="${row.get('bug_id')}"/></td>
<td><c:out value="${row.get('creation_ts')}"/></td>
<td><c:out value="${row.get('summary')}"/></td>
```

You have a list of maps. So essentially the row holds a map in each iteration. You can use the notation `row.get('key_name')` to get the value against that key from the map.

And also make sure that this taglib is added at the top of the jsp page as the second line.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c"       uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

Comment: tried this but it did not work and no errors generated

Comment: Ok can you change this line ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> bugList=oc.getbugList(null); to ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> bugList=oc.getbugList(null);

Comment: Are you sure your list does have data?

Comment: yes I have tested it with sysout it has data and also changed Object to String

Comment: Please see my edited answer now. It looks like you are missing the taglib entry at the top. If you are using tomcat you might need to add the tag library to tomcat as well.

Comment: I am already using it, below are the imports I am using:- <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page language="java" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@page import="java.util.Map"%> 
    <%@page import="java.util.HashMap"%> 
     <%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>

Comment: Can you please share the entire jsp page here. From top to bottom. This is actually working for me. I have checked.

Comment: If jstl is properly added then this .get('key_name') will work.

Comment: @muasif80- Thank you for help. I have resolved it and posted the solution. Please help me in understanding why the earlier code was not working. Reference to "IncomingBugs" servlet was correct or not as I do not want to use java in jsp.

Comment: Actually I have just setup this code and i successfully used it. So the request.setAttribute was correctly used above in your code and it correctly passed it to the jsp page. There might be some other reason. If you can share the whole jsp page before this solution it can help.

Secondly this code scriptlet approach that you have used in your solution is not recommended.

Comment: Were you hitting the jsp page url directly or hitting the servlet url. If you were hitting the jsp page url directly then on first access it will not have the data, it will only get data after it is forwarded from servlet to the jsp page.

Secondly, right now you have put all the code for loading of data inside jsp so now direct access to jsp will have the data .

Comment: In the previous state you can check the list size by using this ${list.size()} See if it was zero or not. If you were coming directly to the jsp it must be zero.

You need to put your jsp into the previous state in order to debug this and understand this.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it, by moving the code of IncomingBugs.java to jsp but I am still not able to figure out that why the arraylist is not passed from java to jsp file?
Can't we refer servlet from jsp 'form action="IncomingBugs"' in this manner?

Below is the fix:-

```
 <%
            OracleConnection oc=new OracleConnection();     
            try {
                ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> bugList=oc.getbugList(null);

                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> blr=new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                 for (HashMap<String, Object> bugMap : bugList) 
                {
                     HashMap<String,String> bl=new HashMap<String, String>();
                     String bugzilla_id = bugMap.get("bug_id").toString();
                     String creation_ts = bugMap.get("creation_ts").toString();
                     String short_desc = bugMap.get("short_desc").toString();
                     String status_whiteboard=bugMap.get("status_whiteboard").toString();
                     bl.put("bug_id", bugzilla_id);
                     bl.put("creation_ts", creation_ts);
                     bl.put("short_desc", short_desc);
                     bl.put("status_whiteboard", status_whiteboard);
                     blr.add(bl);

                }
                 request.setAttribute("list",blr);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
          %>


  <c:forEach items="${list}" var="maps">
  <tr>
  <td>${maps['bug_id']} </td>
  <td>${maps['creation_ts']} </td>
  <td>${maps['short_desc']} </td>
  <td>${maps['status_whiteboard']} </td>
  </tr>
  </c:forEach>
```